# VSTO 2010 Outlook Addin -Exclude Embedded Object

Tags: c#, visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing a outlook 2010 add-in with c# .net  using Visual Studio 2015.

When i click on the button (add-in) in the reading pane of an email, I need to save only the attachments excluding the embedded objects of that particular email.

```
if (item.Attachments.Count > 0)
{
    for (int j = 1; j <= item.Attachments.Count; j++)
    {
        item.Attachments[j].SaveAsFile(item.Attachments[j].FileName);
    }
}
```

But my current code copies both the attachments and embedded objects, I only want to save the attachments (not the embedded objects)

Could anyone please help me on this?

Comment: `item.Attachments[j]` smells like it's going to be of type Attachment.  It probably has a bunch of properties and stuff.  Have you looked at the properties and seen what they are when the Attachment is truly an attachment and when it's embedded?

Comment: Thanks Will. I will check on it